# ansible only first shell command is executed

Tags: ansible

Following is my yamal file,

```
---

     - hosts: qa-workstations

       tasks:

           - name: update java version
             shell: echo "asdfasdf" > /tmp/abc
             shell: echo "asdf" >> /tmp/abc
```

If I execute ansible using below command,
ansible-playbook test.yml -k

It executes only 1st shell. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have a task for every command you issue - it is also easier to debug

Answer (score 3):

If you want a task execute many commands, you can use `with_items` loop:

Example:

```
tasks:
  - name: test
    shell: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - echo Ansible
      - df -h
```

But if you have many commands, you should use [script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) module. `script` module copies your shell script to remote machine and executes it.

Answer (score 3):

You've actually only defined a single task here.  The second `shell` line simply overrides the first.  The proper way to write this is:

```
---

 - hosts: qa-workstations

   tasks:

       - name: create /tmp/abc
         shell: echo "asdfasdf" > /tmp/abc

       - name: Append to /tmp/abc
         shell: echo "asdf" >> /tmp/abc
```